# Why isn't the tag autocompletion suggesting 6 tags while they are at least 6 available?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-autocomplete

I wonder why sometimes the tag autocompletion suggests fewer than 6 tags even though they are at least 6 tags available.

Example: the tag [github-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-desktop) isn't suggested when typing `github-`:

[image]

Bug or by design?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @rene first select a tag, then you'll see what OP is describing. It's as if the tag "takes the place" of the suggested tags.

Comment: @rene It's because "github" is returned as a valid match but then excluded for already being in the list of tags

Comment: @Tim but expected behavior is to always show the maximum (up to 6) available tags, isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably, but since only six are returned including the one it excludes it doesn't have another to put there. It's definitely a bug, even if it's one introduced by a conscious design decision not to make the search more complex by taking into account the already-selected set of tags

Comment: @TimStone [I've asked a related](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/766/12102) *why is withholding an obvious tag done 'by design'* kind of question. As I [mention here](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/766/#comment3210_767), " ...there IS plenty of room for more tags to be displayed in that box, and yet it hides the one I need to see - by design!"

Comment: @TimStone also curious if there is an appeal process for someone adding the `by-design` tag to my question, which I have a feeling tends to have a *nothing-to-see-here-mooooove-along* effect prematurely.